# Azure PHP web app using system assigned managed identity connecting to Azure Storage Blob

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I need to connect an azure web app to a storage account using system assigned managed identity. My APP is using PHP. Did the configuration following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-storage?tabs=azure-portal%2Cprogramming-language-csharp and is ok.

The example there is using C# I can’t find an example with PHP. Anybody knows how to connect an azure web app with PHP using system assigned managed identity to a storage account blob?

Thanks,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**There is no `library` in `PHP language` for access the blob stotage from Web APP using System Managed Identity**

**The Only Available language is C# and Node.js**

**You Can raise this issue in [*github*](https://github.com/issues) might be you can get some help from there**

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong in understanding your question correctly, but when you use a system managed identity, your app service or VM should be registered as an identity and you should not program any settings in your code, at least this is how I use system managed identities.

I apply two steps:

1. I retrieve the MSI token from the App Service directly
2. I call my Azure Service using this access token

The variables $_SERVER['IDENTITY_ENDPOINT'] and $_SERVER['IDENTITY_HEADER'] are available the moment you enable Managed Service Identity on the Azure resource you're making use of. This is the "secret sauce" that has been abstracted away in the libraries and scripts you can find online.

The basis of this operation is described in a [Microsoft Documentation on how to access Managed Identity credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=%2Fazure%2Factive-directory%2Fmanaged-identities-azure-resources%2Fcontext%2Fmsi-context&tabs=portal%2Chttp).

Here's an example where I use the PHP curl extension to give you a glimpse under the hood of what needs to be done:

```
<?php

echo nl2br('Hello World from Azure!' . PHP_EOL);

$vaultResource = sprintf(
    'resource=%s&api-version=%s',
    urlencode('https://vault.azure.net'),
    '2019-08-01'
);
$headers = [
    'Accept: application/json'
];
$curlOptions = [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'AzurePHPDev/1.0.0',
];

$tokenUrl = sprintf(
    '%s/?%s',
    rtrim($_SERVER['IDENTITY_ENDPOINT'], '/'),
    $vaultResource,
);
$headers[] = 'X-IDENTITY-HEADER:' . $_SERVER['IDENTITY_HEADER'];
$token = '';
$tokenHandler = curl_init($tokenUrl);

curl_setopt_array($tokenHandler, $curlOptions + [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers]);
if (false === ($token = curl_exec($tokenHandler))) {
    echo nl2br(sprintf('Can not connect: %s', curl_error($tokenHandler)) . PHP_EOL);
    exit;
}
curl_close($tokenHandler);
$parsedToken = json_decode($token, true);

$key = 'Foo';
$secretUrl = sprintf(
    'https://identityphpdemokv.vault.azure.net/secrets/%s?api-version=7.2',
    $key
);
$headers[] = sprintf('Authorization: Bearer %s', $parsedToken['access_token']);
$secret = '';
$secretHandler = curl_init($secretUrl);
curl_setopt_array($secretHandler, $curlOptions + [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers]);
if (false === ($secret = curl_exec($secretHandler))) {
    echo nl2br(sprintf('Can not connect: %s', curl_error($secretHandler)) . PHP_EOL);
}
curl_close($secretHandler);
$parsedSecret = json_decode($secret, true);

echo sprintf('The secret for %s is %s', $key, $parsedSecret['value']);
```

The resulting output is:

```
Hello World from Azure!
The secret for Foo is Bar
```

There's a composer package that works with managed identities if you're interested in it. See https://github.com/wapacro/az-keyvault-php for details.

Hope this answer helps you further, if not let me know and I'm happy to help. Good luck!

Comment: PS: in this example I used Azure Key Vault, but you can apply this also on your Azure Storage Account for Blob Storage container access.